# How can I backup my people group?

Tags: backup, windows-live

When I initialized my Windows Phone, I lost my group (I did synchronise my live account).

Until I used windowsphone, searching a person by group was very convenient...

Is it impossible to back up groups into a live (Hotmail) account?

Answer (score 2):

If you store your contacts in [Windows Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live), those will be backed up. However, groups you create cannot be at this time.

Check out the [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) tag for information on what can be backed up, as well as some workarounds for other things.